# Bootstrap - Do you need .col-*-12 within .row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to understand if you should **always** include an element with class `col-lg-12` (or `md`, `sm`, etc., of course) within an element with class `row`.  Or if you only need to be consistent one way or another.

If you were inconsistent, is the only issue that you'd wind up with some padding differences as seen in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NATqKq51EWeHGu0VqBg7?p=preview)?  The second row - the one whose immediate child has the class `col-lg-12` - has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` set at 15px whereas the first row does not.

Comment: Who says you always have to include an element with the class `col-lg-12`?

Comment: @j08691: That's my question.  It would seems like all of Bootstrap's examples do it that way.

Comment: Bootstraps grid system is based on 12 columns. You can have less/more, but it's there so that you can target it specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you don't include it, it will just default to the widest width you have defined, but will not have any padding on the sides which can lead to bad UX. Better to remove the padding if you don't need it with an override.

I think it's good practice to do it all the time so you know what it is and if you need to change it will save time, it's also how it was built. I have some custom styles as well to get rid of nested col padding so it doesn't always double up just because I need to augment the layout.